# why link doesn't work when I use getStaticProps?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm new in next js and I'm working on project using NextJS. I have some lots in my items page that shows lots currently(`pagination/items.tsx`) and I also have `lotDetails` page that I want it to show details of each lot using dynamic route(`lotDetails\id\index.tsx`).

This is the folder structure:

[image]

Now when I click the Link in `Items.tsx` I expect it to go to `lotDetails` page and pass the props, but nothing happens! (It stays on Items page!). here is `Items.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from "next/link"
 const Items = ({currentItems}:{currentItems:any}) => {
   console.log(currentItems)
  //  const ids=currentItems.map((el:any)=>el.id)
  //  const paths=ids.map((el:any)=>{params:{id:el.toString()}})
  //  console.log(paths)
  return (
    <>
    <div className="container">
      
      <div className="row">
        {currentItems.map((el:any)=><div className="col-md-3 ">
         //this should be linked to lotDetails page!
          <Link href={{pathname:"../lotDetails/[id]",query:{id:JSON.stringify(el.id),title:el.title,image:el.image,description:el.description.toString(),rate:el.rating.rate,count:el.rating.count,price:el.price},}} as={`/lotDetails/${el.id.toString()}`}>
          
          <div className="lot">
            
        <div className="img-container">
          <img src={el.image}/>
        </div>
        <div className="title">
          {el.title}
        </div>
        <div className="price">
          <span className="price-title">Price:</span>
          <span>{el.price}</span>
          
        </div>
        </div>
        </Link>
        </div>)}
        
      </div>
    </div>
    </>
  )
}
export default Items;
```

I'm using `getStaticProps` and `GetStaticPaths` in `lotDetails`:

```
 const LotDetails = (props:any) => {
   
const dispatch=useDispatch();
console.log(props)
const lotCount=1;

const addLots=()=>{
dispatch(AddCustomerLot({...props,lotCount:lotCount}))
}
  return (
    <>
   
    <div className='container lot-details'>
     <div className="row" >
     <div className="col-md-6">
         <div className="detail-container">
           <div className="title-details"><h3>{props.title}</h3></div>
           <div className="badge"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar}/><span>{props.rate}</span></div>
           <div className="inventory">
             Inventory: <span className="count">{props.count}</span> 
           </div>
           <div className="description-details">{props.description}</div>
         <div className="price">Price: <span className="price-number">{props.price}$</span> </div>
         <button className="btn btn-regist" onClick={addLots}>Add to shopping basket</button>
         </div>
         
         
         </div>
       <div className="col-md-6"><img src={props.image} alt="" /></div>
      
       
     </div>
     </div>
    </>
    
  )
  }
export const getStaticPaths:GetStaticPaths=async(context:any)=>{
  const response= await axios.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")
  
  
const paths=response.data.map((el:any)=>({params:{id:el.id.toString()}}))
console.log(paths)
return{
paths,
fallback:'blocking'
}
}
 export const getStaticProps:GetStaticProps=async(context:any)=>{
 

  
  return{
    props:
      {
      //recieve props
        id:context.query.id,
          title:context.query.title,
          image:context.query.image,
          description:context.query.description,
          rate:context.query.rate,
          count:context.query.count,
          price:context.query.price
      }
    
      
    
  }
}


export default LotDetails;
```

when I deleted `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths`, the link worked! So I receive that link works perfectly and the problem is in `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths`. Of course I don't want to use `getServerSideProps`.
**Update**
According to julio's suggestion I changed pathName, and I also changed context.query to context.params.id:
Items:

```
 <Link href={{pathname:`/lotDetails/${el.id}`,query:{id:JSON.stringify(el.id),title:el.title,image:el.image,description:el.description.toString(),rate:el.rating.rate,count:el.rating.count,price:el.price},}} as={`/lotDetails/${el.id.toString()}`}>
          
          <div className="lot">
            
        <div className="img-container">
          <img src={el.image}/>
        </div>
        <div className="title">
          {el.title}
        </div>
        <div className="price">
          <span className="price-title">Price:</span>
          <span>{el.price}</span>
          
        </div>
        </div>
        </Link>
```

lotDetails:

```
 return (
    <>
   
    <div className='container lot-details'>
     <div className="row" >
     <div className="col-md-6">
//I removed all section which used props and querys using comments
         {/* <div className="detail-container">
           <div className="title-details"><h3>{props.title}</h3></div>
           <div className="badge"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar}/><span>{props.rate}</span></div>
           <div className="inventory">
             Inventory: <span className="count">{props.count}</span> 
           </div>
           <div className="description-details">{props.description}</div>
         <div className="price">Price: <span className="price-number">{props.price}$</span> </div>
         <button className="btn btn-regist" onClick={addLots}>Add to shopping basket</button>
         </div> */}
         
         
         </div>
       {/* <div className="col-md-6"><img src={props.image} alt="" /></div> */}
      
       
     </div>
     </div>
    </>
    
  )
  }

export const getStaticPaths:GetStaticPaths=async(context:any)=>{
  const response= await axios.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")
  
  
const paths=response.data.map((el:any)=>({params:{id:el.id.toString()}}))

console.log(paths)
return{
paths,
fallback:'blocking'
}
}

 export const getStaticProps:GetStaticProps=async(context:any)=>{
 

  
  return{
    props:
      {
      
        id:context.params.id,
          // title:context.query.title,
          // image:context.query.image,
          // description:context.query.description,
          // rate:context.query.rate,
          // count:context.query.count,
          // price:context.query.price
      }
    
      
    
  }
}
```

Comment: `getStaticProps`'s [`context`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-props#context-parameter) does not have access to query params. It only has access to `context.params.id` that's passed from `getStaticPaths`.

Comment: Also, the `pathname` for the link to the `lotDetails` page should look like ``pathname: `/lotDetails/${el.id}`.``.

Comment: @juliomalves tnx for comment I tried `/lotsDetails/${el.id}` but it does not work yet  and I removed context.query and just used context.params.id . It doesn,t work yet

Comment: Is the issue still the same? Does clicking on the link still stays on the same page, or are you seeing a different issue now?

Comment: @juliomalves It's the same issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved problem in two steps:

1-I'm using google chrome browser, so I configured chrome and added my localhost port:

I used this link: chrome://inspect/, clicked configure button and added my localhost port(in my case localhost:3000)

2-I added this code to lotDetails page(the page which I used axios)

```
axios.defaults.httpsAgent=new https.Agent({
  rejectUnauthorized:false,
})
```

don't forget to import:
`import https from "https"`
Now It's working.